# Php loop giving an extra HTML element in output

Tags: php, html

```
<?php
$sun=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `red_users` WHERE `role`='user' AND `userID` != '$userID' ORDER BY `id` DESC LIMIT 10 ") or die(mysql_error());

while($su[]=mysql_fetch_array($sun)){

}

for($i=0;$i<count($su);$i++){

    $sud=$su[$i]['userID'];
    $sname=$su[$i]['name'];
    $dop=$su[$i]['dp'];
    $sxx=$su[$i]['sex'];

    if($dop != ''){
        $sey=$dop;
    }

    if($dop =='' AND $sxx=='MALE'){
        $sey="../images/male.png";
    }

    if($dop =='' AND $sxx=='FEMALE'){
        $sey="../images/female.png";
    }
?>

<a href="profile.php?frnd=<?php echo $sud ?>">
    <div class="inbox-item">
        <div class="inbox-item-img"><img src="<?php echo $sey ?>" class="img-circle" alt=""></div>
        <p class="inbox-item-author"><?php echo $sname; ?></p>
    </div>
</a>
<?php } ?
```

In output an extra Html element (with no dynamic data) is displaying.
After the Real elements which are populated by mysql query an extra element is displaying which contain no data.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of

```
while($su[]=mysql_fetch_array($sun)){

}
```

and further processing of `$su`

process every record in the same `while`:

```
while($su=mysql_fetch_array($sun)){
    // do stuff
}
```

Additional note by @mloureiro:

This because the `while` keeps running till it find a `false` value, so when the `mysql_fetch_array` doesn't have anything else to return, it will give `false` that will be passed to the `$su[]` array.

Comment: it will run the while loop over and over again.so the page will be slow

Comment: You will run **one** `while` loop instead of **two** loops. Are you sure page will be slow?

Comment: @MuhammedAsif that doesn't make sense, I'm not an expert in mysql methods, but using the *while + for* just looks redundant.

Comment: @MuhammedAsif can you test this answer please?

Comment: I think I understand the question of @MuhammedAsif, the thing is instead of having the statements inside the `for`, move them to the `while`

Comment: Ok, if two loops are faster then one - do two loops, but remove `[]` from `while` because of the reason @mloureiro wrote.

Comment: and the i get a slow loading page

Comment: @MuhammedAsif ok... I believe you, I don't have any idea why.

Comment: Are you certain that the slowness you encountered wasn't due to something else? u_mulder's answer is the way the [MySQL docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-array.php) show as examples.